# QML WebView unable to run javascript

Tags: javascript, qt, webview, qml

So I tried to run the following code on Windows 10 (Qt 5.13):

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtWebView 1.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    WebView{
        id: webView
        anchors{
            top: button.bottom
            bottom: parent.bottom
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }

        url: "http://google.com"
    }
    Button{
        id: button
        text: "Click me"
        onClicked: {
            console.debug("Running javascript")
            webView.runJavaScript("document.title", function(result) { console.log(result); });
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button I get the following:

```
qt.winrtrunner.app: The WinRT WebView only supports calling global functions, so please make your call in the form myFunction(a, b, c). Also note that only string arguments can be passed.
```

What does that mean? Why isn't the console displaying the title of the website? Also could someone clarify for me what is the "callback" function in `WebView::runJavascript(script, variant callback)` which is documented [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebview-webview.html#runJavaScript-method)?

Comment: If your trying to accomplish displaying the title of the current page, I would recommend using the title attribute of the WebView. The callback function gets called after the Javascript function has been executed, with the return value of the function as parameter. This is done so that your program flow can continue, without having to wait for the WebView's Javascript function to return, because that may take some time to complete.

Comment: @Chris so my intention was not to get the title, I just wanted to test the `runJavaScript()` function and was asking why my code didn't work (and why I get that message as I am not sure what are "global functions"). Anyway your clarification about the callback function is useful.

Comment: I can't test exactly why it isn't working, but my guess is that `window.title` is not a function, but a variable. The global scope in Javascript is the root scope that is available in every other scope. A scope determines which variables you can access. For a more elaborate explanation, I would suggest you to read (a part of) https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope